# How to get ez components ezcImageTransformation quality under control?

Tags: php, zeta-components

I am testing the ImageConversion component of ez components, but I just can’t get the quality of the outcoming image under control.

```
$converter->createTransformation( 'thumbnail', $filters, array( 'image/jpeg', 'image/png' ) );

try
{
$converter->transform(
'thumbnail',
$image,
$uploadPath.$filename.'_thumb.'.$ext
);
new ezcImageSaveOptions(array('quality' => 70));

}
catch ( ezcImageTransformationException $e)
{
die( "Error transforming the image: <{$e->getMessage()}>" );
}
```

If I remove the line `new ezcImageSaveOptions(array('quality' => 70));` I get a “fuzzy” jpeg.

If I have it in the code, I get a 100 % quality image.

Anyone, any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: I would of though instantiating that object (`ezcImageSaveOptions`) on its own would not affect the `transform()` method being called above.

Answer (score 1):

You need to submit the `ezcImageSaveOptions` to the `createTransformation()` method in order to make it work. See the [documentation of `createTransformation()`](http://incubator.apache.org/zetacomponents/documentation/trunk/ImageConversion/phpdoc/ezcImageConverter.html#createTransformation).

The 'quality' parameter should control the compression of the resulting JPEG. Did you try playing with different values here and compare the results? Which back end are you using, GD or ImageMagick?